# Xmonad and panels in gnome-shell

Tags: 12.04, gnome, xmonad

I run 12.04 with gnome-shell (so it looks like Gnome 2 with horizontal panels on the top and the bottom of the screen) with Xmonad.

What I want to do is create a keybinding that would toggle these panels, basically switching applications on the screen to fullscreen and back.

Can anyone tell me what should I write in `xmonad.hs` in order to achieve it? (I'm totally innocent of Haskell, unfortunately.)

Comment: I changed "borders" to "panels" in your question since that's the term which is used

Comment: Yes, thanks, I felt that something was wrong with wording.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've setup your XMonad using gnomeConfig then the panels should be handled as struts.

In your `xmonad.hs` you then want to use the [ManageDocks module](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-ManageDocks.html).

The docs page provides the steps necessary to enable it but it surmounts to modifying your `manageHook` and `layoutHook` as follows:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
...
manageHook = ... <+> manageDocks
...
layoutHook = avoidStruts (tall ||| mirror tall ||| ...)
        where tall = ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2)
...
```

There already exists a key binding in XMonad to toggle struts: <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is the default. If you're defining your own set of keybindings then you can add the following:

```
,((modm, xK_b     ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)
```